# Глобальный хук клавиатуры с целью изменить клавишу

Tags: c++, клавиатура, keyboardhook

Возможно ли с помощью глобального хука клавиатуры (SetWindowsHookEx, WH_KEYBOARD_LL) изменить получаемую им клавишу
(при этом изменить так, чтобы до всех получателей дошла именно измененная версия этой клавиши)?

Пытался сделать это с помощью следующего кода, но ничего не вышло.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK llkp(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){

    if(nCode==0 && ((PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam)->vkCode==VK_SPACE)
        ((PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam)->vkCode=0x5A; //меняем VK_SPACE на клавишу "Z"

    return CallNextHookEx(hh,nCode,wParam,lParam);

}
```

Готов заплатить за решение.

Comment: Если требуется ответ да\нет - то ответ да, это возможно. Если вы хотите более развернутого ответа - потрудитесь поработать хоть чуть чуть сами и приведите пример что у вас уже получилось, и задавайте вопросы по тем частям кода которые не работают\не получается реализовать.

Comment: Отлично.
Уже имеется код, сейчас выложу.

Comment: Готово. Таким образом пытаюсь изменить клавишу. Но ничего не выходит. При нажатии на пробел выводится только пробел.

Comment: А перехват то происходит? ловушка работает? в общем и целом код выполняется?) и как проверяете что подмена не сработала?

Comment: Может вы хотите сделать просто ремаппинг клавиш? Типа новая раскладка клавиатуры?

Comment: Перехват работает. Я до ретёрна (return) добавляю строку выводящую на экран все попадаемые в коллбэк (callback) клавиши. А проверяю так, что попросту выбираю какое-либо из окон в Windows'е, кликаю на пробел и вижу, что окно получает только пробел (а не "Z", как предполагалось).

Comment: Хочу просто изменить одну клавишу на другую и всё. К примеру, пользователь кликает по клавише "Q", а выполниться вместо неё должна клавиша "W".

Comment: Там кажется не буквами надо оперировать, а скан-кодами клавиш, по этому и не работает. Буквы идут уже потом, а перехватывать он должен сканкоды.

Comment: А вы можете привести пример кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, это не работает. Смысл хуков - отслеживание событий, а не активное воздействие на них. Тем не менее, хук позволяет отменить событие, вернув из процедуры единицу, так что оно не дойдет до целевого приложения. Тогда вы можете сгенерировать вместо него свое с помощью SendInput:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{        
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
            if(p->vkCode == VK_SPACE) {

                INPUT ip;
                ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                ip.ki.wScan = 0; 
                ip.ki.time = 0;
                ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;    
                ip.ki.wVk = 0x5A; //Z
                ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // key press
                SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

                ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // key release
                SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

                return 1;
            }           
            break;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

События, сгенерированные SendInput, могут восприниматься некоторыми приложениями не так, как настоящие события клавиатуры.

Comment: Понятно :(
Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Ничего писать не надо. Для ремаппинга клавиатуры в духе *пользователь кликает по клавише "Q", а выполниться вместо неё должна клавиша "W"* можно воспользоваться утилитой [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339)

Comment: А через обычный глобальный хук клавиатуры это вообще никак реализовать нельзя?

Comment: @ИванИванов Можно наверное. Но я затрудняюсь так с ходу описать...

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Но мне в любом случае не подходит ваше решение.
Мне нужен именно код, а не готовая утилита/программа.